# Node Mocha file glob slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have my test files along side my code, like the following:

```
-- controllers
  -- controller.js
  -- controller.spec.js
```

When I run mocha only on the folder, it runs quickly

```
mocha './lib/controllers/*.spec.js'
```

If I run mocha for all spec files, it takes a lot longer per **it block**

for example:

```
mocha './lib/**/*.spec.js'
```

Does anyone know why this may be or how I can speed it up.

**Note:** I'd like to keep the test files along side the code and the folders aren't predictable.

**Update 14:52 - exact comparison**

Time to run difference

```
mocha "lib/controllers/**/*.spec.js"  26.23s user 0.48s system 100% cpu 26.496 total
```

**Total**: 26.23s

```
mocha "lib/controllers/user1/*.spec.js"  1.84s user 0.11s system 101% cpu 1.920 total
mocha "lib/controllers/user2/*.spec.js"  1.37s user 0.07s system 101% cpu 1.426 total
mocha "lib/controllers/user3/*.spec.js"  2.44s user 0.15s system 100% cpu 2.560 total
mocha "lib/controllers/user4/*.spec.js"  2.00s user 0.14s system 101% cpu 2.111 total
mocha "lib/controllers/user5/*.spec.js"  2.31s user 0.16s system 99% cpu 2.473 total
mocha "lib/controllers/user6/*.spec.js"  4.00s user 0.16s system 100% cpu 4.126 total
```

**Total**: 13.96s

Comment: Interesting, are the delays evident in the Mocha test output? i.e. are tests actually affected or just the time to output the results? Also what OS?

Comment: The actual tests themselves are mostly < 3ms. The time taken between running each test can be up to a second. OS: Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @carlcheel People use "test" to refer to a single `it`, and they use "test" to refer to an entire run of `mocha ....` at the command line. You should edit your question to clarify what you are talking about. Among things you could do (depending on what you actually mean) would be showing the output of the run or the time results given by `time mocha ...`, or both. And we may yet still need to see a [mcve] to know what the actual issue is.

Comment: @Louis updated with further detail

Comment: So are you saying there are no more folders other than `user` that contain tests?

Comment: Updated with a direct comparsion for one folder. There are many other folders which substantially increases the time to run.

Comment: Did you ever find out the reason for the slowness?